# Sudo tx with subxt

Tags: subxt

I'm writing a script with subxt. How can I wrap a set_code tx in a sudo_unchecked_weight tx?

Current code:

```rust
    let sudo_set_code: Payload<SetCode>  = nodetemplate::tx().system().set_code(code);
    let weight = Weight {
        ref_time: 0,
        proof_size: 0,
    };
    let sudo_tx = nodetemplate::tx().sudo().sudo_unchecked_weight(sudo_set_code, weight);
```

Traceback:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:29:67
   |
29 |     let sudo_tx = nodetemplate::tx().sudo().sudo_unchecked_weight(sudo_set_code, weight);
   |                                             --------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `RuntimeCall`, found `Payload<SetCode>`
   |                                             |
   |                                             arguments to this method are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected enum `RuntimeCall`
            found struct `subxt::tx::Payload<SetCode>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `test_sudo_subxt` (bin "test_sudo_subxt") due to previous error
```

Comment: We'd like to support your "current code" eventually somehow, but it's tricky, so alas at the moment you indeed need to use the generated types manually to construct any "inner" extrinsics. We'll get there eventually I hope!

Answer (score 4):

Solved it:

```rust
  let call = nodetemplate::runtime_types::node_template_runtime::RuntimeCall::System(
        SystemCall::set_code {
            code: wasm_binary.expect("could not decode wasm binary").into(),
        },
 let sudo_tx = nodetemplate::tx()
        .sudo()
        .sudo_unchecked_weight(call, weight);
```

Full code can be found here:
https://github.com/uptest-sc/submit-runtime-upgrade/blob/main/src/main.rs